# Which of the following hostnames are valid?

Tags: http, url-scheme

This is from my lecture slides in the web based systems section of Distributed Systems:

> Which of the following hostnames are valid?
>   122.65.132.11.1.97
>   My_server
>   300.320.1.32

The answer is: All three can be valid depending on the scheme used.

I would have thought the answer would be that none are valid; can someone explain why all three could be valid?

Comment: consider asking a question.

Comment: Explain why the answer is all 3?

Comment: Perhaps hostname is not the best term because that's too much associated with DNS; I believe they refer to whatever follows the scheme ... certainly `My_server` is a valid hostname albeit not canonical.

Answer (score 0):

First: the ip address is the actual name of the host.  Everything else is DNS entry that maps to the ip address.

122.65.132.11.1.97 is a valid IPv6 ip address.

My_server is a valid DNS entry (which presumably could map to a legit host).

Corrected:
300.320.1.32 is a not a valid IPV4 ip address.

Comment: Don't 300 and 320 fall outside of the range of an IPv4 octet?